# WebRTC data channel connection establishment with separate offerer and answerer roles

Tags: javascript, networking

I've developed a demo application for demonstrating connection establishment using WebRTC data channels. I am using cross-window communication using `postMessage` for a signalling channel replacement. The intention of the demo is to get the connection going without any extra work - no compiling, no socket.io keys, no usernames, nothing. Offerer and answerer and explicitly broken apart, the code for them is not generalized to a concept of a *peer* on purpose as that's how intend to apply it (offerer always initiates).

I'd appreciate a code review of the WebRTC connection establishment flow. The code is as minimal as possible, but still quite large for a SO question. The [repository is on GitHub](https://github.com/TomasHubelbauer/webrtc-data-channel-demo/tree/70dab436bd910ede5763ede61446dfe691e9c30f).

Here's the log that I get with this demo:

```
[answerer] received offerer offer
[offerer] onsignalingstatechange have-local-offer
[offerer] onicegatheringstatechange gathering
[answerer] set offerer description
[answerer] onsignalingstatechange have-remote-offer
[answerer] received offerer candidate
[offerer] received answerer answer
[answerer] onsignalingstatechange stable
[answerer] added offerer ice candidate
[answerer] onicegatheringstatechange gathering
[answerer] oniceconnectionstatechange checking
[offerer] onsignalingstatechange stable
[offerer] oniceconnectionstatechange checking
[offerer] set answerer description
[answerer] onicegatheringstatechange complete
[offerer] received answerer candidate
[offerer] onicegatheringstatechange complete
[offerer] added answerer ice candidate
[offerer] oniceconnectionstatechange connected
[offerer] oniceconnectionstatechange completed
[offerer] onopen
[answerer] oniceconnectionstatechange connected
[answerer] ondatachannel
[answerer] onopen
```

Here's the offerer code shrunk-down as much as possible:

```
let peerConnection;
let dataChannel;

function receiveMessage(data) {
    switch (event.data.type) {
        case 'start': await initializeAndSendOffer();
        case 'answerer-answer': await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(event.data.answer); break;
        case 'answerer-candidate': await peerConnection.addIceCandidate(event.data.candidate); break;
    }
}

async function initializeAndSendOffer() {
    peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [ { urls: [ 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' ] } ] });

    peerConnection.onicecandidate = event => {
        if (event.candidate)
            passAlong({ type: 'offerer-candidate', candidate: clone(event.candidate) });
    };

    dataChannel = peerConnection.createDataChannel('test');

    dataChannel.onmessage = ...

    const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
    passAlong({ type: 'offerer-offer', offer: { type: offer.type, sdp: offer.sdp } });
}
```

Here's the answerer code shrunk down as much as possible:

```
let peerConnection;
let dataChannel;

function receiveMessage(data) {
    switch (event.data.type) {
        case 'offerer-offer': await initializeAndSendAnswer(event.data.offer); break;
        case 'offerer-candidate': await peerConnection.addIceCandidate(event.data.candidate); break;
    }
}

async function initializeAndSendAnswer(offer) {
    peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [ { urls: [ 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' ] } ] });

    peerConnection.ondatachannel = event => {
        dataChannel = event.channel;
        dataChannel.onmessage = ...;
    }

    peerConnection.onicecandidate = event => {
        if (event.candidate)
            passAlong({ type: 'answerer-candidate', candidate: clone(event.candidate) });
    };

    await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);
    const answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
    passAlong({ type: 'answerer-answer', answer: { type: answer.type, sdp: answer.sdp } });
}
```

Notes:

- This is susceptible to MITM given the signaling channel is insecure (HTTP). SRTP itself is secure, but it is possible for an attacker to insert themselves as a MITM by substituting peer's SDP for theirs and connection the two peers through themselves.

Questions:

- Is the WebRTC flow generally correct? Any obvious mistakes?
- Do people generally use/worry about unordered signaling channels where a candidate might come before the offer/answer? Should I cover that and hold onto candidates to apply once offer/answer comes?